# HTML Canvas putImageData causing frame overlap

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am trying to read pixels (frame by frame) from websocket and render it on to canvas (in grayscale). Data is being displayed properly, just that pixels of the current frame are displayed overlapped on previous frame. Thus picture gets smudged after few frames.

I am tying to clear out the previous frame before rendering current one. What would be the proper way to do it?

I am using putImageData() to render the frame. I have tried clearRect() before calling putImageData(). and have tried clearing Imgdata (Imgdata.data = [];) array before populating it again but none of these things worked.

```
`   var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var Imgdata = context.createImageData(100,100);
    var numPixel = Imgdata.data.length/4;   

 ws.onmessage = function (event) {
            var bytes = new Uint8Array(event.data);
            console.log("data: " + numPixel + " bytes: "+ bytes.length);
            //Imgdata.data = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < numPixel; i++) {
                Imgdata.data[(i*4)+Math.round(bytes[i]/85)] = (bytes[i]%85)*3;
                Imgdata.data[(i*4)+3] = 255;

                Imgdata.data[(i*4)+0] = bytes[i];
                Imgdata.data[(i*4)+1] = bytes[i];
                Imgdata.data[(i*4)+2] = bytes[i];
                Imgdata.data[(i*4)+3] = 255;

            }
            //context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            context.putImageData(Imgdata,0,0);
        };
`
```

Comment: draw a blank rectangle over the canvas between each frame

Comment: @dandevis , I tried inserting blank frame like this. Is it correct ? because no luck with this code also.                                                                         
                                                                                                                       `var blank = context.createImageData(canvas.height, canvas.width);
            context.putImageData(blank,0, 0);
            context.putImageData(Imgdata,0,0); `

Comment: i mean like draw a rect on the canvas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say the cause is most likely due to the first line inside the for loop, without knowing the data i dont know what it does but id does not look right.

```
// ???
Imgdata.data[(i*4)+Math.round(bytes[i]/85)] = (bytes[i]%85)*3;
```

If the data is random then this would randomly set one of the colour channels of each pixel.

Apart from that I can not see any errors that would cause what you describe.

I have rewritten the code only as a suggestion to improve the performance a little.

```
    const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
    const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    const imgdata = context.createImageData(100,100);
    const pix = imgdata.data; 
    pix.fill(255); // set all to 255 To cover the alpha channel
    const numPixel = pix.length;   // best leave as byte count

    ws.onmessage = function (event) {
        const inData = event.data;  
        var inIndex = 0; 
        var i = 0; 
        while(i < numPixel){
            pix[i ++] = pix[i ++] = pix[i ++] = inData[inIndex ++];
            i++; 
        }
        context.putImageData(imgdata,0,0);
   };
```

That should work event if the incoming data is incomplete the function putImageData completely replaces the pixels. If any pixels are undefined from the socket data they will be set to zero and will show up as black.

Comment: Thanks both of you!  calling black fillRect() before calling putImageData() did the trick.